# JQuery Version issue with Internet Explorer Version 11 , IE 11

Tags: jquery, html, version, internet-explorer-11, jquery-1.10

I am facing issues in using Internet Explorer 11 with jQuery 1.10. From JQuery browser support info, they suggest to use jQuery 2.X versions. But updating the version will be a big effort for our application. Is there a patch available for compatibility of Jquery 1.10 to make it work on IE 11.
The IE console shows these messages.

*File: jquery-migrate-1.1.0.js, Line: 6, Column: 2
SCRIPT5009: 'jQuery' is undefined
File: bootstrap.min.js, Line: 6, Column: 1
SCRIPT5009: 'jQuery' is undefined
File: jquery.hoverIntent.js, Line: 33, Column: 2
SCRIPT5009: 'jQuery' is undefined
File: jquery.cluetip.js, Line: 20, Column: 3
SCRIPT5009: '$' is undefined*

Answer (score 0):

From the errors, it looks like you've failed to load jQuery. `jquery-migrate-1.1.0.js` isn't jQuery, it's something you load *after* jQuery to add back deprecated/removed features. If it can't find the `jQuery` symbol, then you've left jQuery off or there was an error loading it. Look in the F12 Developer's Tools for network errors, incorrect URLs, and of course make sure you've included the appropriate jQuery file. jQuery 1.x works just fine on IE11.